# How To Suggest Google A New Design

Tags: google-calendar, user-interface, google-feedback

I was just wondering, if and how it is possible to suggest a new design to Google? Because it just happened that I thought, this would be a more pleasant design of the current Google Calendar and would like to suggest it as an inspiration to the design team. In my opinion, this version would be lighter, cleaner, and faster to read:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you have G Suit:

> Submit a feature idea Currently, you can only submit feature ideas in
>   English.
>
> Important: To view or submit feature ideas, you'll need to contact G
>   Suite support first to verify your account credentials. It can take up
>   to 24 hours after your request to get access to the Feature Ideas
>   Community.
>
> - Sign in to the [**Cloud Connect Community**](https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/).
> - On the CCC home page, click the **G Suite and Chrome Feature Ideas** tile.
> - Search the Feature Ideas Community to see if your idea already exists.
> - If you see something that looks similar to your idea, review it before submitting your idea to avoid duplication. Tip: Make sure you
>     vote on feature ideas that you support.
> - Select **View all feature ideas** and click **Add ⊕**.
> - Add a product category to make your feature idea easier to find.
> - To improve your submission, include a problem statement, the desired behavior, and a possible solution or alternative.
> - Click **Post**.
>
> Your idea will then be available for other members of the community to
>   browse and vote on.
>
> The feature ideas that get the most votes are submitted to the Product
>   Teams. If your idea is submitted, you also earn a badge on Cloud
>   Connect Community.
>
> **https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762**

---

- if you have a regular account: **https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/**